# Xamarin iOS : Web View User authentication and SAML Authentication

Tags: authentication, xamarin.ios, saml

I am implementing SSO for my app. I am facing the following problem.

1.) SSO page opens up in web view. How to close the web view after the user is authenticated ? And also how should I capture the cookie or data after login ? Is there any way ?

2.) Backend is using SAML auth. How to implement in my app ? I am using Xamarin iOS for development.

Answer (score 0):

There are two official document here:

For the first question:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-v1-enable-sso-ios

For the second question:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-v1-debug-saml-sso-issues

These docs can guide you to start project.After that , if have detailed questions ,you can ask new questions.